# Why can't I delete a branch in a remote GitLab repository?

Tags: git, gitlab

I'm trying to delete a branch both locally and in a remote GitLab repository. Its name is `origin/feat`. I tried `git push --delete origin feat`. Git complains:

```
remote: error: By default, deleting the current branch is denied, because the next
remote: 'git clone' won't result in any file checked out, causing confusion.
remote: 
remote: You can set 'receive.denyDeleteCurrent' configuration variable to
remote: 'warn' or 'ignore' in the remote repository to allow deleting the
remote: current branch, with or without a warning message.
remote: 
remote: To squelch this message, you can set it to 'refuse'.
remote: error: refusing to delete the current branch: refs/heads/feat
```

OK makes sense, so I tried switching to `origin/master` with `git checkout master` and it tells me: `Already on 'master'`. Does the current branch also need to be set in the remote directory? How would I do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Edit (per comments by OP—I have not used GitLab): GitLab has a web interface with dropdowns.  You need the one under the Settings view (not the Project view).  Choose a branch in the Settings view under "Default branch" and click "Save changes" to set the current branch on the server.

#### Details

You have the right idea, but you have to remember that there are *two* repositories—two Gits—involved.

Any time you get text prefixed with `remote:`, this means the text is coming from the *other Git*.  So when you have your Git ask the other Git to delete `feat`, it's the other Git complaining that `feat` is the current branch.

Hence:

> Does the current branch also need to be set in the remote directory?

Yes (well, "instead of" rather than "also").

> How would I do that?

In general, the same way you do it with any repository: log in, `cd` to the repository directory, and run `git checkout`.  But there's a hitch or two with push-able repositories on servers:

- It's on the server.  Are you even allowed to log in?  If not, you need some alternative (which is server-specific).
- It's probably a `--bare` repository, so that you can't use `git checkout` directly.  The trick here is to use `git symbolic-ref` to update `HEAD`:

  ```
  git symbolic-ref HEAD refs/heads/master
  ```

  Of course, this assumes you can log in (see first point).  If there is, say, a web interface that lets you change the current branch on the remote, it is going to have to do this `git symbolic-ref` operation for you.

Comment: I see, thanks. GitLab does provide a web interface and there's a dropdown to switch between branches, but it doesn't seem to be linked to git since I keep getting the same error message.

Comment: @speedymcs: Odd. I wonder if there are server logs you can examine to find out what happens (or doesn't happen) when you use the web interface.

Comment: I managed to delete the branch remotely now. In GitLab there are actually two dropdowns to switch the branch, one in the Project view, one in the Settings view of the respective project. Choosing a branch in the Settings view under "Default branch" and clicking "Save changes" makes git switch to that branch server-side. The dropdown in the project view just decides what files you're looking at in the interface.

Answer (score 67):

Try

```bash
git push origin --delete <branch-name>
```

Answer (score 45):

To remove a local branch from your machine:

```
git branch -d <branch-name>
```

To remove a remote branch:

```
git push origin :<branch-name>
```

**In your case the above statements would be:**

To remove a local branch from your machine:

```
git branch -d feat
```

To remove a remote branch:

```
git push origin :feat
```

Answer (score 13):

I had the same issue when I wanted to delete the master from origin.

**Assuming you want to delete the master**, I resolved the problem in 3 steps:

1. Go to the GitLab page for your repository, and click on the
   “**Settings**” button.
2. In **Default Branch**, switch the default branch from your master to
   other one.
3. In **Protected Branches**, if there's any protection, unprotect the master.

Then you try again to delete the branch.

If it's not the master you want to delete, just follow the same steps with the desired branch.

Comment: Settings than "Repository" than Default Branch.

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying todelete multiple branches, any protected branch (eg the default branch, usually `master`) will cause the whole request to fail, so maybe try delete them one at a time, or excluding known protected branches.

For example, I was trying to delete merged branches with

```
$ git fetch  mygitlabremote --prune; \
    git branch --remotes --list mygitlabremote/* --merged \
    | cut -d/ -f2 | grep -v master \
    | xargs git push mygitlabremote  --delete
$ git fetch  mygitlabremote --prune
```

Answer (score -1):

To delete branch

git branch -D registryDB(a Git branch name)

git push  origin :registryDB